# semisolvable hopf algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I have stumbled upon the definitions of upper and lower semisolvability for Hopf algebras in the paper on classification of semisimple Hopf algebras of certain dimension.

And I have two questions:

1) Is upper semisolvability and lower are equivalent for finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebras?

2) How well does semisolvability define a semisimple finite dimensional Hopf algebra? Can we deduce how comultiplication acts on different elements of our algebra if the algebra is semisolvable?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand you second question? What do  you mean by «define»? How could the property of semi solvability determine the comultiplication?

Comment: I mean maybe there is certain properties of comultiplication that must be satisfied for a semisimple Hopf algebra to be semisolvable?